# URL shows /index.php in URL when viewing site through HTTP, but not when using HTTPS

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, http, https

Visiting any of the below links works fine, and there is no `/index.php` in the URL.

1) https://kdev.solutions

2) https://www.kdev.solutions

However, if you try to visit the site using HTTP, you will get redirected to the HTTPS version, but there will be `/index.php` in the URL now. How do I get rid of this?

1) http://kdev.solutions

2) http://www.kdev.solutions

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    #get rid of index.php in home
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/(.*)$ https://kdev.solutions/$1

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # redirect to HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove** this line:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/(.*)$ https://kdev.solutions/$1
```

This configs is enough for redirect non-https to https (you already have it):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: I still get `/index.php` in the url when I type "kdev.solutions" or "www.kdev.solutions" into the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorder your rules by keeping all redirect rules before internal rewrite rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # redirect to HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301,NE]

    # remove index.php
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]    

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

Also make sure you clear your browser cache or test in a new browser.

Comment: If I use that file, I get this when I navigate to the webite: https://s20.postimg.org/y9u4gbtb1/webpage.jpg

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if I use different browser :(